# Java reflection Vs Javassist

Tags: java, reflection, javassist

I'm currently using Java Reflection to achieve reflective property. I understand there are many a tool to achieve reflection property. One among them is: Javassist, which along with the behavioral reflection, provides structural reflection. However, I'm concerned only about behavioral reflection.

My question is: which among the existing libraries (Java reflection/Javassist/any other) would be good at achieving behavioral reflection? I'm worried only about the performance (i.e. the speed at which they act).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you let us know what is "bahavioural reflection" and "structural reflection"

Comment: I just want to implement the introspection. I don't want to modify the class during the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need introspection, then use `java.lang.reflect` or `java.beans`. Alternatively, you can use some higher-level utilities like [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/).

Comment: Thanks Bozho. I'm just starting to use reflection. However, from several forum threads I read, I realize "reflect" is slow. I was searching for alternative tools and Javassist was one of them. In order to understand the difference (in terms of performance) between reflect and javassist I put up this question. 
Thanks

Comment: reflection is not _that_ slow, and if you perform it only once (and cache the result), it will be fast.

Comment: Thanks Bozho. May be I'm wrong. But, I'm more interested in knowing  the difference in performance between java.lang.reflect and javassist.

Comment: I don't know if there is. And you shouldn't care that much, it's not critical.

Comment: I'm also going to say it: if you can avoid using reflection in the first place, that's much faster all around.

Comment: @Ashok: Are you sure your code is performance-critical enough for all that to make any difference at all?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: As I told before, I'm initially investigating to make a decision between java reflection and javassist. But, I'm sure my code will be performance-critical.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these articles:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/94356

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0610/

Javassist is much faster if your code needs high throughput for accessing methods or fields, and load time is not critical for you.

If you are using JDK1.7, you can take advantage of InvokeDynamic with almost the same performance as calling the method directly, hence no need for javassist.

---